# Capture parameterized string from MyBatis @Select query

Tags: java, oracle, annotations, mybatis, ibatis

I'm running into an issue with a query my Java app is executing against an Oracle DB. Taking the query from exception and replacing the parameters (denoted as ? in the exception log) has it running fine in the DBA tool.

So I want to get a good look at the parameters being set in the final query that's actually being passed to Oracle, and I can't find a clear way to grab that from the @Select annotation.

I've been curious on doing that for a while, so this question is specifically about if it's possible to grab that parameterized query being sent to Oracle, not the specific query or error I'm getting. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you check [Mybatis logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749846/mybatis-log4j-how-to-confiure-log4j-to-print-sql-log-to-file?answertab=active#tab-top)?

Comment: Additionally make sure that in the adHoc query you use the same connection user and setting as configured for MyBatis.

Answer (score 0):

This is described in [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html)

In a nutshell:

1. configure the logging provider you use in `mybatis-config.xml`
2. depending on the provider set `TRACE` logging level for the mapper you are interested in

For `logback` provider this is described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718097/how-to-configure-logback-for-mybatis-to-print-my-sql). For log4j mybatis documentation has more than enough information.